# How to synch a project with same name in different RTC components?

Tags: stream, components, rtc

I have the following setup.

**Project Area 1 

RTC Stream 1 : Component 1 : Eclipse project Project A 

RTC Stream 2 : Component 1 : Eclipse project Project A : default flow target is RTC Stream 1**

Project Area 2 
RTC Stream X : Component X : Eclipse project Project A

Note that the eclipse project name is the same and the contents are related to the same work.

Project Area 2 belongs to a different team and the two teams need to be able to synch changes with each other.

I can easily synch the contents between RTC Stream 1 and 2 by changing flow target of one to the other and accepting the changes.

**How can I bring the changes in Project A in Component X into Project A of RTC Stream 1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I bring the changes in Project A in Component X into Project A of RTC Stream 1?

By adding `componentX` in RTC `Stream 1`: a project can include components "owned" by another project.

Answer:
**You could export a change set as a patch, and apply that patch in your project in 1.**

Comment: If I do this then I will have 2 eclipse projects with the same name in RTC Stream 1 (albiet across 2 components). I don't want this. I want Project Area 1 to have all its projects in a single component. when i load a rep-workspace based on what you are suggesting, one project will overwrite the other one in my local workspace.

Comment: @Ajay But the content of those two components would be the same?

Comment: No, I don't need the changes from Project Area 1 to go into Project Area 2. But need the latest from Project Area 2 in Project Area 1. Its a one way from 2 to 1.

Comment: You could export a change set as a patch, and apply that patch in your project in 1.

Comment: will this allow me to merge the changes from Project Area 2 into Project Area 1. Meaning, will I be able to to see the differences in the Comparison Editor?